# Vim ctags current directory and gemset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, rvm, ctags

I've got two Ctags commands that work great.

This first one builds tags for my current gemset of my rails project

```
ctags -R \`bundle show rails` /../*
```

and this second one which generates ctags for the actual working directory of my rails project

```
ctags --extra=+f -R *<CR><CR>
```

However, when I run each one it overwrites the current tags file so that I can't enjoy ctags for both my gemset and my current directory.

Can somebody show me how I can get these two commands to combine and produce one tags file with all the ctags in it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your second ctags command, try using the `-a` flag.  According to the documentation:

```
 -a, --append
      Append to existing tag file.  (For vi-format tag files,
      see also --update.)
```